# WordPress shortcode display as plain text

Tags: shortcode, page-template

I have a custom templates and I used custom shortcodes to displayed it in the page. But the shortcode is not working, its displayed as plain text only. I already deactivate and reactive the plugin but still have same issue.

I have a custom templates and I used custom shortcodes to displayed it in the page. But the shortcode is not working, its displayed as plain text only. I already deactivate and reactive the plugin but still have same issue.

I'm using this [info_box_calculator] but it display as plain text or sometimes it gives me a blank page

How to fix this?

```
function info_box_calculator(){
ob_start();
get_template_part('page-calcu-info-box');
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('info_box_calculator', 'info_box_calculator');
```

[Link](http://www.homecredit.ph/4537-2/6367-2/)

Comment: Would you mind to show your code inside `get_template_part('page-calcu-info-box');`

Comment: Please mention in which file you have placed the code for shortcode? functions.php of theme or any plugin's file? or any other file?

Comment: your probably doing the add_shortcode too late.

Answer (score 2):

First of all as far as I know that you can't call `get_template_part()` from your plugin.It's a Theme only function . Try to keep your calculator code's in a php file inside your plugin's directory and include it like bellow:

```
function info_box_calculator_core(){
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'mydir/calculator.php');
    //replace 'mydir/calculator.php' with your file name 
}
add_shortcode('info_box_calculator', 'info_box_calculator_core');
```

Let me know if it works for you.